# WHERE sql integrating an IIF

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having trouble getting a Where statement to work when I try an IIF statement.  I have tried a few variations of the sql to no avail.  What I am trying to do is count holidays *Gain* up to a certain date.  When I use my Between statement alone it works fine.  When I try to reset the counter after the system clock goes past 5-20-13, I return no results when it should show 1 for the Memorial Day holiday that just passed.The segment of code that I can not figure out the proper syntax on is

```
WHERE (((SchedulingLog.EventDate)=IIf(Date()>DateSerial(Year(Date()),5,20),((SchedulingLog.EventDate) Between DateSerial(Year(Date()),5,20) And DateSerial(Year(Date())+1,5,20)),((SchedulingLog.EventDate) Between DateSerial(Year(Date())-1,5,20) And DateSerial(Year(Date()),5,20)))))
```

Below is my entire sql.

```
SELECT Roster.UserID, SchedulingLog.Category, 
Sum(IIf([CatDetail] Like '*Gain*',[Value],0)) AS Gain, DateSerial(Year(Date()),5,20) AS ResetDate, Date() AS [Date]
FROM SchedulingLog INNER JOIN Roster ON SchedulingLog.UserID = Roster.UserID
WHERE (((SchedulingLog.EventDate)=IIf(Date()>DateSerial(Year(Date()),5,20),((SchedulingLog.EventDate) Between DateSerial(Year(Date()),5,20) And DateSerial(Year(Date())+1,5,20)),((SchedulingLog.EventDate) Between DateSerial(Year(Date())-1,5,20) And DateSerial(Year(Date()),5,20)))))
GROUP BY Roster.UserID, SchedulingLog.Category, DateSerial(Year(Date()),5,20), Date()
HAVING (((SchedulingLog.Category) Like "DH*" Or (SchedulingLog.Category) Like "Comp*"));
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is twofold, first you're looking for where your DATE = BETWEEN Date and Date.  Not sure if that's a problem in Access, syntax is usually WHERE Date BETWEEN Date and Date. 
2nd issue is trying to return a command in the IIF statement, rather than returning values to be evaluated by the BETWEEN statement.

I believe this should work:

```
SELECT Roster.UserID, SchedulingLog.Category, 
Sum(IIf([CatDetail] Like '*Gain*',[Value],0)) AS Gain, DateSerial(Year(Date()),5,20) AS ResetDate, Date() AS [Date]
FROM SchedulingLog INNER JOIN Roster ON SchedulingLog.UserID = Roster.UserID
WHERE SchedulingLog.EventDate BETWEEN IIf(Date()>DateSerial(Year(Date()),5,20)
                                                ,DateSerial(Year(Date()),5,20)
                                                ,DateSerial(Year(Date())-1,5,20))
                             AND IIf(Date()>DateSerial(Year(Date()),5,20)
                                                ,DateSerial(Year(Date())+1,5,20)
                                                ,DateSerial(Year(Date()),5,20))
GROUP BY Roster.UserID, SchedulingLog.Category, DateSerial(Year(Date()),5,20), Date()
HAVING (((SchedulingLog.Category) Like "DH*" Or (SchedulingLog.Category) Like "Comp*"));
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!!!  So the key if I am reading this right is the AND If statement when using the Where clause?

Comment: BETWEEN needs a VALUE, followed by AND, then another VALUE,  IIF statements can just return a value, they can't return the AND operator.